# Facebook Send - How to find out who message recipients are

Tags: facebook

I'm building a site that I've integrated with [FB Send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/). Is there any callback that will tell me who the messages were sent to if a user on my site uses FB Send?

Comment: What info do you get out of the `message.send` event? (details in your link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is no callback from Facebook for the FB Send button you referenced. There is not currently any way to retrieve the list of recipients for which a user has just messaged via send button, sorry.

Comment: I can't think why a workaround for this would be used - if you want users to send trackable invites you should use app requests (which you'll get info about in both the callback and when they're accepted)- for once-off significant actions you can have them post on a friends' wall (and you get a post ID back for this action which can be tracked later) but the Send button is designed for user - user private messages containing a link attachment. If you have permission to access a user's private messages you could see the resultant thread but i can't imagine users wanting to give that permission

Comment: This is by design, I believe, as we require developer to ask for the `read_mailbox` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) in order to read a user's facebook inbox. So it is possible, just not directly from the send button functionality.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, that helps a lot.